# More "approved" components than were added

Tags: deployment, change-set

So I was using salesforce Change Sets to send a project from sandbox to production. I have control over both so I know what is outgoing and what is incoming. I was sending some fields and a layout (30 fields + 1 page layout). However on the incoming side it verfied 32 out of the the 31 components being deployed. Yet it looks like it has less than 31 anyway. Is this just a bug or what is happening here?

[image]

Comment: Maybe Salesforce just started a "Free Component Monday" program?  Seriously though, I haven't noticed change set deployments over-counting components in the past.  Maybe it's counting the object itself as being updated as well?

Comment: The tests just finished running (took forever, not fond of this system) and the "Deploy Components" reverted back to 31/31 with a full green bar. So I suppose it was just a glitch while it was validating,

Comment: I haven't got a screen shot, but I've had some groovy numbers on deployments lately, like 163/42, that give a progress circle that looks like a fish. It hasn't affected the deployment.

Comment: Oh good point I hadn't realized the circle was actually bending to a different shape, that could be fun.